# Inserting multiple values from an array using array_unshift() method

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

`array_unshift` is using for inserting one or many values at the beginning of an array. Now I have an array-

```php
$data = [1, 3, 4];
```

Another array is needed to insert at the beginning of the `$data` array.

```php
$values = [5, 6];
```

Here I want to insert the values `5, 6` at the beginning of the `$data` array, and the resulting `$data` would be-

```php
$data = [5, 6, 1, 3, 4];
```

**Note:** I know there is a way like `array_unshift($data, ...$values);` but this is working from `php7.3.x` AFAIK. I need to do it below `php7.3`.

Is there any way to do this without looping the `$values` array in the reverse order?

Comment: Use `$data = array_merge($values, $data);` Look example: https://phpize.online/?phpses=439eab6d7d3b11ffa1827608f95f1ae0&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I am being stupid. It's a great idea. @SlavaRozhnev write it as an answer I will accept this.

Comment: Probably beneficial to show researchers this related page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51250941/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) exists since PHP 4:

```
<?php
$data = [1, 3, 4];

$values = [5, 6];

$data = array_merge($values, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Live [PHP sandbox](https://phpize.online/?phpses=439eab6d7d3b11ffa1827608f95f1ae0&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 2):

You should use array_merge instead of array_unshift.

```
$data = [1, 3, 4];
$values = [5, 6];

$result = array_merge($values, $data); // the sequence of the array inside array_merge will decide which array should be merged at the beginning.
```

Comment: This is identical to the @SlavaRozhnev answer.

Comment: I see but when I sees that answer, I already posted mine too. Not an issue the aim is to get a solution.

Comment: You still can find a better solution or an alternative solution. This will help other.

Comment: This one gets a vote for additionally explaining how array_merge works with the orders